# Track and Field statistics database problems

Tags: database, database-design

Hey guys I was hoping someone could steer me in the right direction! I've been working on this for a while and, I won't lie, it is for a class, but, I am making it for our college too. It's basically a database to keep track of stats from meets. An example of what I want it to do is, lets say someone runs the 800m run and they run a 1:58 or something, well that person will have that stat to their name, if that makes sense. But anyway here are my tables.

By the way, this will go into a MySQL database, and will be used from a web interface, not access. But this is what I have so far, and for some reason, it's not really making sense to me...

AthleteTable(
AthleteID
AthleteFirstName
AthleteLastName
AthleteDOB
AthleteHome
AthleteHighschool
AthleteYear
AthleteGender
AthleteWeight
AthleteHeight
AthleteEvents)

AthleteParticipationTable(
AthleteParticipationID
EventID
AthleteID
T_F_ID
EventMark)

EventTable(
EventID
EventName
EventLocation
EventDate
EventSeason)

Track_and_Feild_Event_Table(
T_F_ID
EventName)

The Athlete table is just that, it's the athletes themselves. The Athlete Participation is what events the athletes ran/jumped/threw etc... in the meet. The Event Table is something one of my teachers suggested I put in there, and that's the one I'm having troubles with. In the Event table, it's an autonumber but in the the athleteparticipation, it's a number. And the Track_and_Field table is all of the possible events in track and field.

I guess, I was just wondering if I'm even going at this the right way and if anyone can help that'd be glorious.

And if I didnt explain everything well enough just tell me what you want me to elaborate on and I will do that

Answer (score 0):

I think you are on the right track with the Athlete, Event, and Track and Field Event tables.

The AthleteParticipation only needs to record that the athlete took part in the events. However you need a results table which records the round (heats, quarters, semis, and finals) plus and the mark they achieved. The idea is that the athlete can have one or more results depending on how many they participate in.

You may also include the day of the results, if the events last more than one day. This may be beneficial later when you are developing statistics for the athlete.